# quick way to scripting or creating programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, scripting

what's a good way to scripting or creating programs unders windows?

Comment: It depends - what types of programs do you mean? Do you have a specific goal, or are you just looking to learn?

Answer (score 4):

How about [python](http://www.python.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

You will need Notepad, and to learn JScript (not Javascript... JScript), VBScript or Batch. Then you can easily create small scripts, somewhat equivalent to bash shell scripts on Linux.

For the first two, you can read the [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950396.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) is becoming the new Windows scripting language. Being a full .NET language, it is inevitably much more powerful that the horrible old batch scripts one used to have to write (and still retains much of the syntactic sugar of scripting/shell languages).

Comment: +1 I wrote my first practical powershell script a couple of weeks ago. Love it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do VBScript without the need to install anything.

Open notepad and enter the following text:

```
MsgBox "Hello"
```

Save it as *filename.vbs*
Double click the file you just created, congratulations - you just created and ran a VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to plug AutoIt. It's a free download and comes with it's own editor that can be quickly/easily installed anywhere. The language is very rich and comes with a large library of user defined functions. Integrated context-sensitive help with syntax display. There's even a GUI editor. A final plus is that it compiles to .exe so will run on any win2k/xp/vista/2k3/2k8/7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Python for scripting on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A vague question usually gets a vague response.

Download a compiler or interpreter and find a tutorial.

With more information we can better point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are three clever choices here:

Scripting: Use JSCRIPT because much of what you learn about JSCRIPT can be used in Javascript. You can either graduate to Javascript/AJAX in the browser, or Microsoft .HTA apps.

Or, you could use Python because it has standard modules to do just about anything a sysadmin would do plus addons to access Windows .COM objects and WMI. You can then either graduate to Python on a UNIX platform, Jython (which is Python in the JVM) or IronPython which opens up the entire world of .NET for you.

And there is of course, the non-scripting choice which is about creating programs under Windows. If you choose this you probably have an end-game in mind that is beyond scripting, so start with SharpDevelop and IronPython. Then, as you gain confidence, start working with C# still using the same Sharpdevelop toolset. With this choice you can also graduate to UNIX applications using the MONO .NET environment although if you want to do GUI apps on UNIX you will need to use GTK# instead of Windows Forms.